# Should I use 'a' or 'an' before numbers?

Tags: indefinite-article, numbers, reading-aloud

Should I use 'a' or 'an'  before numbers? Suppose that we have this sentence:

> Their implementation results achieved a (or an?) 85-90% accuracy rate.

Comment: The choice of "a" or "an", is like no other rule of spelling, because it isn't a rule of spelling. It is a rule of speaking.  It is 100% determined by how you say the following word - how you write it is completely irrelevant. (Actually 99.9% because there among the minority of people who use phrases like "an historic occasion" there are a very few who actually pronounce the 'h' in such cases).

Comment: @Colin Fine: I think you're mistaken about ***an** historic*. This is one of a very few cases where some *extremely* carefully-spoken Brits make a specific point of aspirating the ***/h/*** after ***an***. Since I wrote [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21818/how-do-you-pronounce-the-h-in-an-historian#comment36571_21819) several years ago it's become pretty clear to me that practically every time I hear it (which turns out to be *a lot*, since I've developed "blue car syndrome" regarding the usage), it's from someone I would call a careful speaker.

Comment: And these "_extremely_ carefully-spoken Brits" amount to something other than a very few among a minority, @FumbleFingers? ;-)

Comment: @Colin Fine: Well, it's hard to say (mainly because of "blue car syndrome"). Obviously there are four theoretically possible permutations, within which I'd exclude **a 'istoric** as effectively "unpronounceable" anyway. But my gut feeling is that whereas **a historic** is unquestionably the *most* common of the other three, I think **an historic** is actually more common than **an 'istoric** (at least, if we restrict ourselves to apparently reasonably competent native speakers on the BBC, or giving lectures on Youtube, etc.).

Comment: Maybe. But if I encounter "an historic" and read it normally, I won't sound the 'h'.

Comment: Interesting...never paid due attention before. +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends how you would read it;

... achieved an eighty-five to ninety percent ...

So "an" in this case. But

... achieved a seventy-five to eighty percent ...

"a" because seventy doesn't begin with a vowel (when you speak it).

Answer (score 5):

It is based on how it *sounds*. Example:

```
a 1    a 2    a 3    a 4    a 5    
a 6    a 7    an 8   a 9    a 10

an 11  a 12   a 13   a 14   a 15
a 16   a 17   an 18  a 19   a 20
```